# When is Heimdall coming to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, heimdall

I want to install [Heimdall](https://bitbucket.org/benjamin_dobell/heimdall/downloads) to my Ubuntu 14.04. 
I however did not find any official support for it, particularly for 14.04. I know the previous packages but would like to have a direct support.

When is the Heimdall support coming for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: No. 14.04 is LTS so I would expect packages to be directly to it.

Comment: you still can install .deb package from that list

Comment: Yes, I know. I need to the same thing for other Linux distro so I need to read the code. Therefore, asking particularly for 14.04 and not golden oldies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What makes you think it's not available? It's right there in the [official repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=heimdall&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all). You just need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install heimdall-flash heimdall-flash-frontend
```

There are also `.deb` packages right there in the link you posted in your question.

Answer (score 2):

When I look at the page you linked, I see a lot of support for Ubuntu:

[image]

I would appear that he has not released one since 2013 for Ubuntu, but that supports 13.10, and most stuff on 13.10 works on 14.04 and newer.

I just downloaded `ubuntu13.04-heimdall-frontend_1.4.0-0_amd64.deb` and `ubuntu13.04-heimdall_1.4.0-0_amd64.deb` and they both installed fine with no dependancy issues. Bear in mind I had to use the command `dpkg -i /path/to/downloads/ubuntu13.04-heimdall-frontend_1.4.0-0_amd64.deb` rather than software centre.

---

I guess you want it to be supported on 14.04 officially - that's not sommething we can answer here. You could speak to the developer and tell him that the 13.10 files work on 14.04?